# How i could prevent from duplication Database using mingo

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongo-shell

I use "Use Mydatabase" command in mongo shell to create Database.

I need to make sure that the database with the same name , could not insert again.

How can i prevent Database duplication?

Comment: command [use <db name>](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#working-with-the-mongo-shell) only switch to specified db name database, when you create any collection or insert documents it will create database automatically if database not present otherwise it will update in same database. it will not create duplicate database.

Comment: use `show dbs` command to see the  list of databases